# how to apply IIF condition in mdx query in rows

Tags: mdx

my data are look like this:

```
> Columns  A     B      C       
> 
> Rows     Total Audit Complete Audit Not Complete Audit Total
>          0           1              2            3
>          2           3              4            9
>          4           4              4            12
```

so, i need to change the rows title Audit Total with Audit Totals. the audit total rows is fix name. how to write the condition in mdx query. my mdx query is :

```
> With Member [Measures].[NCs of New
> Audit] as [Measures].[N Cs Of New
> Audit]
> 
> Member [Measures].[PNCs Of New Audit]
> as [Measures].[PN Cs Of New Audit]
> 
> Member [Measures].[OFIs Of New Audit]
> as [Measures].[OF Is Of New Audit]
> 
> Member [Measures].[Average NCs Of New
> Audit] as [Measures].[Average N Cs Of
> New Audit]
> 
> Member [Measures].[Average OFIs Of New
> Audit] as [Measures].[Average OF Is Of
> New Audit]
> 
> 
> 
> SELECT { [Measures].[Audit Closed],
> [Measures].[Audit Open],
> [Measures].[CS Of New Audit],
> [Measures].[NCs of New Audit],
> [Measures].[PNCs Of New Audit],
> [Measures].[OFIs Of New Audit],
> [Measures].[Average NCs Of New Audit],
> [Measures].[Average OFIs Of New Audit]
> } ON COLUMNS,
> 
> {[Results By Functional
> Discipline].[Discipline].[Discipline].AllMembers
> } ON ROWS
> 
> FROM [QualityMattersView] where
> (<<SD>>:<<ED>>,<<Title>>)
> 
> CELL PROPERTIES VALUE,
> FORMATTED_VALUE, CELL_ORDINAL,
> FONT_FLAGS, FORE_COLOR, BACK_COLOR
```

i want to write some iif condtion in rows, so if i get rows="Audit Total" then it replace by "Audit Totals".

Comment: thanks for reply. i change the mdx query but i get the error: error running data source query. my change mdx query is:

Answer (score 1):

One not very elegant solution is something like :

```
StrToSet( 
   Replace( 
      SetToStr(...[Discipline].AllMembers )
   ,'[Audit Total]'
   ,'[Audit Totals]' )
,CONSTRAINED)
```

You can also remove one element from a list {} - your member, and add the new one.

Comment: thanks for reply. but can you please say how can i use this one in my above mdx query.

Comment: StrToSet is going to return a set, change {[Results By Functional Discipline].[Discipline].[Discipline].AllMembers} with the StrToSet expression

Comment: SELECT
{[Measures].[Audit Open], [Measures].[Audit Closed], [Measures].[New Audit]}
ON COLUMNS,

{(StrToSet(Replace(SetToStr([Results By Functional Discipline].[Discipline].AllMembers),'[Audit Total]','[Audit Totals]'),CONSTRAINED))}

ON ROWS

FROM [QualityMattersView 1] where <<Parameter>>

Comment: this is my change mdx query. i applied in pps. but i got the error: error running in datasource query. please help.

Comment: maybe the replace function is working differently, check the function for replacing text, it's not a standard MDX function.